# This code for Telegram bot suposse to work because I copyed it, but does not

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I started learning making bots in Telegram with Python 3. I was learning it by this course https://groosha.gitbook.io/telegram-bot-lessons/. In a lesson 2 there was a code

```
    import telebot

    bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

    @bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
    def find_file_ids(message):
        for file in os.listdir('music/'):
            if file.split('.')[-1] == 'ogg':
                f = open('music/'+file, 'rb')
                msg = bot.send_voice(message.chat.id, f, None)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg.voice.file_id, reply_to_message_id=msg.message_id)
            time.sleep(3)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

and it must work like: I put some audio files in the music folder, and then the bot sends to me the audio id.
But when I copy this code, I am getting the same error every time:

```
2020-01-30 19:16:09,945 (util.py:66 WorkerThread2) ERROR - TeleBot: "NameError occurred, args=("name 'os' is not defined",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sergej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 60, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "N2.py", line 7, in find_file_ids
    for file in os.listdir('music/'):
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N2.py", line 17, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\Sergej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 392, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Sergej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 416, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Sergej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 109, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\Sergej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Sergej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 60, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "N2.py", line 7, in find_file_ids
    for file in os.listdir('music/'):
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the interpreter said, you are using `os` module's function without importing it. You have to import it at the top of your code, like

```
import os
import telebot
# Your code...
```

Comment: Thanks, but, why it does not work if I import telebot first?

Comment: Actually if you write
`import telebot import os`
It works. The importante thing is that you import the os package before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `import os` statement at the top of your code. 
Keep learning!